# Continue Looping If Same Random Number is Duplicate

Tags: php

I want to generate random article from MySQL database with 5 different article as result. I try using preg_match().

```
$random_post = 5;
$unique_number = "";

do {
    $random_post--;
    $rand_id = rand($min_range, $max_range);
    $unique_number .= " ".$rand_id;

        if (!preg_match("/$rand_id/", $unique_number)) {
            get_article($rand_id);  
        }
} while ($random_post);
```

I also try using strpos().

```
$random_post = 5;
$unique_number = "";

do {
    $random_post--;
    $rand_id = rand($min_range, $max_range);
    $unique_number .= " ".$rand_id;

        if (strpos($unique_number, $rand_id) === false) {
            get_article($rand_id);  
        }
} while ($random_post);
```

But same random number still generated. like 2 6 12 2 6, 13 9 13 3 3, 11 13 13 12 11. I think i use the function incorrectly or having bug in code flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding the new number to your result before you check if it's a duplicate. Because of this, your `if` condition will always be false and you'll never get your articles.

Move these lines inside your `if` block:

```
$random_post--;
$unique_number .= " ".$rand_id;
```

Comment: Thank you. I dont think about that.

Answer (score 1):

Why use a string to hold this data? I suggest an array:

```
$random_post = 5;
$unique_number = array();

do {

    $rand_id = rand($min_range, $max_range);

        if (!in_array($rand_id, $unique_number)) {
            get_article($rand_id);  
            $unique_number[] = $rand_id;
            $random_post--;
        }


} while ($random_post);
```

If you need a string made of these numbers for another purpose you can use implode:

```
$unique_string = implode(" ", $unique_number);
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be done through the PHP? You can do something similar using SQL:

```
SELECT your, things FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
```

Which selects 5 distinct entries, never the same twice

Comment: I read on somewhere that rand() will get all data so it will slow the query. So i change to php.

Comment: @Yusufmm `RAND()` works per row to select something, so if you have a **lot** of rows (read: well over 15,000) you will start seeing some performance impact. It's really dependant on the scale of your data, much like any `foreach` style function

Comment: here http://www.titov.net/2005/09/21/do-not-use-order-by-rand-or-how-to-get-random-rows-from-table/ and some other sources say it slow. I still search for some info about your statement.

Answer (score 1):

Short and simple script:

```
$ids = range($min, $max);
shuffle($ids);
foreach(array_slice($ids, 0, $random_post) as $id)
    get_article($id);
```

if you have a lot of articles I'd use something like

```
$ids = array();
while(count($ids) < $random_post)
{
    $id = rand($min, $max);
    if(!isset($ids[$id))
        get_article($ids[$id] = $id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : It will use `rand` only required numbers of times.

```
//Create an array with available range
$items = range($min_range, $max_range);
//Number of posts
$posts = 5
//Final list
$answer = array();

for($x = 0; $x < 5; $x++) {
    //Generate a random number from 0 to number of items available in the array
    $rand = rand(0, count($items) - 1);
    //Get the item at the given random position
    $answer[] = $items[$rand];
    //Remove the used item from the array
    array_splice($items, $rand, 1);
}
```

The above example will generate only 5 random numbers and it will give you required ids.